# Trigger background function from HTTP function in Micronaut gcp application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, micronaut, micronautgcp

There are two types of Cloud Functions in GCP:

HTTP functions, which handle HTTP requests and use HTTP triggers.

Event-driven functions, which handle events from your cloud environment and use event triggers as described in Cloud Functions triggers.

1. Use an HTTP function when you need your function to have a URL
   endpoint and respond to HTTP requests, such as for webhooks.
2. Use an event-driven function when your function should be triggered
   directly in response to events within your Google Cloud project,
   such as messages on a Pub/Sub topic or changes in a Cloud Storage
   bucket.

As per the Google Cloud document https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing

I have a requirement to create HTTP function and that HTTP function should trigger the background function for further processing. Using the micronaut framework I have created two function as HTTP and background function.

**HTTP function**
The controller in http function

```
@Controller("/")
public record FileUploadController(IFileUploadClient iFileUploadClient) {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUploadController.class);
    @Override
    public String getFileName() {
        LOG.info("Get file name is being called");
        iFileUploadClient.pubSubMessage(new PubSubMessage());
        return "This is file 1";
    }
}
```

**Publisher**

```
@PubSubClient
public interface IFileUploadClient {
    @Topic("projects/white-stacker-412404/topics/micronaut-devices")
    void pubSubMessage(PubSubMessage pubSubMessage);
}
```

**Dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut.gcp:micronaut-gcp-pubsub")
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:26.30.0')

    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub'
}
```

**Logs**

```
21:57:58.288 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG i.m.g.p.i.PubSubClientIntroductionAdvice - Created a new publisher[pubSubMessage] for topic: projects/white-stacker-412404/topics/micronaut-devices
```

I am using the local emulator for PUB/SUb https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator. The emulator is running and the env variables are also set.

**Background function**

```
public class Function extends GoogleFunctionInitializer
        implements BackgroundFunction<PubSubMessage> {

    @Override
    public void accept(PubSubMessage message, Context context) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}

class PubSubMessage {
    String data;
    Map<String, String> attributes;
    String messageId;
    String publishTime;
}
```

**Dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut.gcp:micronaut-gcp-pubsub")
    
    // Every function needs this dependency to get the Functions Framework API.
    compileOnly 'com.google.cloud.functions:functions-framework-api:1.1.0'

    // To run function locally using Functions Framework's local invoker
    invoker 'com.google.cloud.functions.invoker:java-function-invoker:1.3.1'
}
```

When `iFileUploadClient.pubSubMessage(new PubSubMessage());` is executed, I am expecting the background function will be trigger, however it is not been trigger.

Emulator log

```
[pubsub] Feb 17, 2024 8:59:00 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
[pubsub] INFO: Detected HTTP/2 connection.
```

If I used the below CURL the background function is triggered

```
curl localhost:8081 \
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "ce-id: 123451234512345" \
-H "ce-specversion: 1.0" \
-H "ce-time: 2020-01-02T12:34:56.789Z" \
-H "ce-type: google.cloud.pubsub.topic.v1.messagePublished" \
-H "ce-source: //pubsub.googleapis.com/projects/MY-PROJECT/topics/MY-TOPIC" \
-d '{
"message": {
"data": "d29ybGQ=",
"attributes": {
"attr1":"attr1-value"
}
},
"subscription": "projects/white-stacker-412404/subscriptions/MY-SUB"
}'
```

**CURL in Emulator return response**

```
curl -XGET $PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST/v1/projects/white-stacker-412404/topics
{
  "topics": [{
    "name": "projects/white-stacker-412404/topics/micronaut-devices"
  }, {
    "name": "projects/white-stacker-412404/topics/micronaut-devices1"
  }]
}
```

GitHub - https://github.com/anandjaisy/gcp-background-function